# wp_insert_post iframe adding

Tags: wordpress, iframe, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i'm developing a wordpress portal.

I'm sending html content(youtube iframe) with ajax from frontend pages. 
But while i'm inserting that post wp_insert_post removes iframe codes in it. There is no problem with ajax or somewhere else. I guess there is somekind of filter.

How can i disable that and insert iframe code ?

Code before inserting -> `$_POST["content"]`

```
<div class="line nVideo" style="text-align: center;" ><iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="650px" height="380px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mY8BZsIgg74?showinfo=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;color=white&amp;origin=http://432designstudio.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div><div id="empty-line" class="nText " ><div>gasdgdsag</div>
```

And after insertation i call content again -> `get_post_field('post_content', $postID)`

```
<div class="line nVideo" style="text-align: center"></div><div id="empty-line" class="nText "><div>gasdgdsag</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has wp_kses function to  makes sure that only the allowed HTML element names, attribute names and attribute values plus only sane HTML entities will occur in $string. You have to remove any slashes from PHP's magic quotes before you call this function.

For your purpose you can try remove this filter by adding this code within your theme functions

```
    function kses_remove_filters() {
    // Normal filtering
    remove_filter('title_save_pre', 'wp_filter_kses');

    // Comment filtering
    remove_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wp_filter_post_kses' );
    remove_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wp_filter_kses' );

    // Post filtering
    remove_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
    remove_filter('excerpt_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
    remove_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
}
```

or just

```
    kses_remove_filters();
```

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: Actually it worked. But do you have any ideas about security issues. What should i be considering about before inserting posts? That content send from users.

Comment: you can set allowed "tags" in this filter i.e you just want to add "class" and "iframe" only.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_allowed_html , and block another "tag" i.e <script>

Comment: I guess half of your message hidden. I checked codex  but i guess it only shows which are allowed. If you know can you tell just how to add iframe besides regular filter setup. Thank you so much btw. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Here a function I found from github https://gist.github.com/woodwardtw/cd09dec40403d6f30a5866a7434bcc83